# Applying Rolling Functions by Group

Tags: r, group-by, na, rollapply, mutate

I am trying to create a new variable in my dataset. The new variable is the three year moving average of the house vote margin. I want to group by the year, state, and congressional district to create this new variable.

I have tried to use both rollmean and rollapply. However, the new column in my dataset is blank. The new column is filled with only NA's. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

test1 <- votemargin %>% group_by(year, state_po, cd) %>%
mutate(rollavg3 = rollapply(house_votemargin, 3, mean, fill=NA))

test2 <- votemargin %>% group_by(year, state_po, cd) %>%
mutate(rollavg3 = rollmean(house_votemargin, 3, fill=NA, align='right'))

Comment: Hello. It would be easier to have some basic sample data with expected result to be able to properly answer your question. One way is to include the result of `dput(votemargin)` or code to create `votemargin`. Keep it minimal :-)

Comment: If you `group_by` year, then all your calculations will be done **within a single year**. So you can't do a three year average, because that requires data from multiple years. Hard to tell if that's your only problem without seeing your data, but at a minimum **you don't want to `group_by(year)`**.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you for your help! I did not need to group_by(year). I am trying to post a picture of my data to help you all out. But I am figuring it out at the moment.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of data. We can't run code on pictures. Instead post a few rows of sample data as text that illustrate the problem. `dput()` is great for that - `dput(votemargin[1:10, ])` would give us the first 10 rows in a copy/pasteable format including all class and structure information. Choose 10-20 rows that illustrate the issue, and preferably post the desired result for the sample input.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.